# Why do I get an error message when I install Travis on my Mac?

Tags: rubygems, travis-rb

> I execute the gem install travis on my MacBookAir with macOS Catalina version 10.15.1
>   Then I get an error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

> Then I exeute sudo gem install travis

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

> How do I install travis?

Answer (score 0):

> I found a solution
> gem install --user-install travis
> and added /Users/steinkorsveien/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin to PATH
>
> get an error when executing travis travis version

```
 /usr/local/bin/travis:
 /usr/local/Cellar/travis/1.8.10/libexec/bin/travis:
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby:
 bad interpreter: No such file or directory /usr/local/bin/travis: line
 2: /usr/local/Cellar/travis/1.8.10/libexec/bin/travis: Undefined
 error: 0
```

> How do I solve this?